# How to not publish data that is already sent to the client in meteor?

Tags: java, android, meteor, publish-subscribe, ddp

I am developing an android client (chat application) using the android-ddp library. The problem is when, everytime I connect to meteor and subscribe to a dataset, all the records are published. How do I stop sending the same records on every new connection and get only the unpublished records.

Comment: are you using a topic, to puclish the data, may be you should try a queue

Comment: yes. Here is my code  `Meteor.publish("message", function (f, t) {
  return Messages.find({from: f, to:t}, {});
});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this. [Reactive Publish](https://github.com/Diggsey/meteor-reactive-publish/)

Comment: Thank you so much. This hopefully will help

Comment: Your Welcome @Deepak .. Happy Coding !!